# Getting an undefined error while running the unit testing in angular

Tags: angular

I have injected the services and the model that have been used in the component.ts file, If I run the spec I was getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'banner_image_url')` to solve this error I have tried several times but it failed the imports and declarations which has been given is correct or need to be changed

In component.ts file

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  subscriptions = new Subscription();
  filteredData: AddLandingPageResponse;
  faChevronLeft = faChevronLeft;

  constructor(
    public location: Location,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public store: Store<StoreState>
  ) {}
}
```

In component.spec.ts

```
  let component: LandingDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LandingDetailComponent>;
  let translateService: TranslateService;
  let mockStore: MockStore<StoreState['landing']>;

 beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LandingDetailComponent, MockComponent(LoadingButtonComponent), SafeHtmlPipe],
      imports: [
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: JsonTranslationLoader },
          compiler: {
            provide: TranslateCompiler,
            useClass: TranslateMessageFormatCompiler,
          },
        }),
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
          preventDuplicates: true,
          closeButton: true,
          progressBar: true,
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState: { ...mockInitialAppState } }),
        Location,
        TranslateService
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LandingDetailComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    translateService = TestBed.inject(TranslateService);
    landingService = TestBed.inject(LandingService);
    mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    translateService.use('en');
  });

 describe('Component', () => {
    it('call the component', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

can anyone help me to solve this error

Comment: Where does the error occur? You don't show the line where `'banner_image_url'` is accessed, so we don't even know what is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `mock` the dependency injections from your component, you shouldn't provide the real ones unless you want to test those...

For example, if you require some data from any of the dependencies, you could mock it using `createSpyObj` from `jasmine` like the following:

```js
const mockTranslateService = 
 jasmine.createSpyObj<TranslateService>('TranslateService', ['use']);


// provide a fake value to be returned by the use() function;
beforeEach(() => mockTranslateService.use.and.returnValue('yourValue'));
```

And then, in your `TestBed` configuration:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [
   // provide the mock service
   { provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService }
  ],
  ....
})

it('creates the component successfully', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

If the first test fails (which validates the component creation), then something is not mocked/configured properly